# Find 8 digit number in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in which the user enters their name, a serial number and the a configuration number. I want to extract that 8 digit serial number to use in a filename.
The cell would look something like this:

> Operator: Jon Doe Date: 07/02/12 S/N:12345678 Cfg:1

I only know how to parse a fixed length (e.g. `value(mid(A1,5,6)`) of text but since name of the user always changes, the length of the text would change.
What function(s) could I use to always guarantee I will only get that 8 digit serial number out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this Excel Formula.

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("S/N:",A1,1)+4,SEARCH("Cfg",A1,1)-(SEARCH("S/N:",A1,1)+4))
```

Assuming that the value `Jon Doe Date: 07/02/12 S/N:12345678 Cfg:1` is in cell A1. Put the above formula in B1

If you still want the VBA Code then you can try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=MID(A1,SEARCH(""S/N:"",A1,1)+4," & _
    "SEARCH(""Cfg"",A1,1)-(SEARCH(""S/N:"",A1,1)+4))")
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks Siddharth! that helps :) I will use this format to make it work  exactly the way I want it.